# Pie chart with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and C#. All of the pie chart controls that I see will only allow each category to be assigned one value.

But what I want to do is show a pie chart which displays multiple values per product.

Is there any solution for this kind of pie chart in ASP.NET?

Comment: What controls have you looked into, and what version of ASP.NET are you using? Telerik has a chart control, and their products tend to be pretty robust.

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at goole charts. They are fantastic and thei API is fairly easy to get along with them.

Comment: I will research the features of graphics Telerik and goole charts. Thanks for yours helps

Comment: I would suggest you to use MS-chart or if you required nice look and feel thn use google charts thay are robust.MS-chart is easy to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,you can use use that by [**Google Charts**](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

> Google chart tools are powerful, simple to use, and free. Try out our
>   rich gallery of interactive charts and data tools.
>
> Google Charts provides a perfect way to visualize data on your
>   website. From simple line charts to complex hierarchical tree maps,
>   the chart gallery provides a large number of ready-to-use chart types.
>
> The most common way to use Google Charts is with simple JavaScript
>   that you embed in your web page. You load some Google Chart libraries,
>   list the data to be charted, select options to customize your chart,
>   and finally create a chart object with an id that you choose. Then,
>   later in the web page, you create a  with that id to display the
>   Google Chart.

**Example**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this..
If u have multiple information can be show in this single chart

```
Check the demo
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6yob172y/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest HighCharts ([Demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/))

They do not rely on canvas like Google Charts so they work on older browser and they have a flexible configuration model and plenty of sample code